# Why is my ImageView hiding when I set it to full screen?

Tags: java, android

I just want to view the small size pics in fullscreen, so I added another ImageView as a fullscreen view named zoom, and when I click back it will hide. However, I can't find the error. I already tried the visibility changes and nothing seems to be wrong:

```
public class HistoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageView v1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
    ImageView v2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    ImageView v3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    ImageView v4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    ImageView v5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv5);
    ImageView zoom = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        v1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        v2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        v3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        v4.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        v5.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        zoom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        v1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        v2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        v3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        v4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        v5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(zoom.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE) {
                    zoom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), CityActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your LogCat?  Did you see what errors / exceptions were produced?  Java error / exception messages are pretty verbose.

Comment: there's no error on logCat but if i run the app go to this activity the its unfortunately stopped.

Answer (score 4):

Do this,

```
ImageView v1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
ImageView v2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
ImageView v3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv3);
ImageView v4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv4);
ImageView v5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv5);
ImageView zoom = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
```

inside your **onCreate**, after `setContentView()` and before,

```
v1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
    v2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
    v3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
    v4.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
    v5.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

You can't initialize your view elements before calling setContentView(). They are just null until then..

Comment: Thanks! it works! =) it took me a lot of time just to solve this!!

Comment: can you accept it as answer? It could help some one else too.. :)